# Problem opening a shapefile in another application

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gpx

I helped a colleague converting waypoints from a GPX file to a shapefile. My colleague has only ArcMap. I gave him the shapefile and when he opened it in ArcMap, it did not show anything in the attribute table.

I installed QGIS in his machine, we tried with a couple of different GPX files and we have the same problem. The resulting shapefile does not show anything in the attribute table in ArcMap, but we are able to see all the data in QGIS.

Any Ideas?

Comment: It seems that the field "url name" messes the things up. I deleted it and now I am able to see the data on the attribute table

Comment: Also I made another experiment and renamed the "url name" field to "urlname" (no space) with the table manager plugin and I am able to see all the info in ArcMap without a problem.

Comment: in general spaces in file names or attributes are discouraged. Use underscores or no spaces wherever possible.

Comment: Furthermore, you might have hit a reserved name as field name.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get "you might have hit a reserved name as field name". Can you explain me what this refers to?

Comment: Soem application do not like field names like "user", "natural" or something else, because these names are reserved inside the programme for internal variables. Unfortuantely, you will not get an appropriate error message in every case. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html for some examples.

Comment: @GerardoJimenez could you answer your own question if that turns out to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As @Craig said: "in general spaces in file names or attributes are discouraged. Use underscores or no spaces wherever possible."